# Visual basic 2010 Simple Airline Reservation

Tags: vb.net

I'm stuck on a problem regarding on Simple airline reservation.

- 10 Textbox are added on the form
- 1-5 textbox are for smokers area only
- 6-10 textbox are non smokers area only.

The twist is by using Inputbox to enter the user input 1 as smokers and 2 as non smokers.

If the user type 1, the seating textbox must be put randomly by a computer and not set by the user (textbox1-5), same goes to non smokers.

Our teacher gave a hint about the making array for textbox but seems its really a clueless on how that thing works.

basically seating reserve.

Not sure in this code of what do I need to add.

```
Dim reserve() As TextBox = {smokingtxt1, smokingtxt2, smokingtxt3, smokingtxt4, smokingtxt5}

Dim reserve1() As TextBox = {nonsmokingtxt1, nonsmokingtxt2, nonsmokingtxt3, nonsmokingtxt4, nonsmokingtxt5}
Dim notification As Integer

notification = InputBox("Enter 1 or 2")

If notification = 1 Then
  For Each i As TextBox In reserve
    i.Text = "Reserve"
  Next
ElseIf notification = 2 Then
  For Each j As TextBox In reserve1
    Randomize()
  Next
Else
  MessageBox.Show("Invalid operation")
End If
```

Comment: What do you have for your `Randomize()` method?

Comment: By the way, `InputBox` is a holdover for Visual Basic - I'd suggest not using it and doing it in a more .NET fashion - perhaps a text box that the user can enter the value in, or even better a ComboBox with a drop down list that they can choose a value from.

Comment: Well I'm just trying to figure out that's why Randomize() method is there.

However our teacher suggested to use Inputbox, to enter 1 for smokers and 2 for non smokers.

Once the process entered, the computer must be assigned randomly from the textbox as "Reserved" until the seats are occupied.

Comment: in our class, visual basic 2010 express is the primarily language program use.

Comment: Off-topic: Pardon me for saying so, but what a stupid assignment you were given! You have to program a GUI, yet the user is supposed to enter `1` for smoker and `2` for non-smoker!? Why not simply use a check box (`[ ] Smoker seat`) for that choice instead? That would save each user the mental effort of making that nonsensical value translation.

Comment: Oh well, there always an alternative way however since our teacher gave these GUI style and the code literally a hard time to figured out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VB6 you used to be able to make an array of controls on an form. This is not possible in VB.NET (e.g. Visual Studio 2010.)

You can achieve what you need done by adding 10 textboxes to the form and then using the following code:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim notification As Integer

    notification = InputBox("Enter 1 or 2")

    Dim RandomInt As Integer

    If notification = 1 Then
    If Textbox1.Text = "RESERVED" And Textbox2.Text = "RESERVED" Then 
        Msgbox "All seats are reserved"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    TryAgain:
        RandomInt = GetRandomInt(1, 5)
        Select Case RandomInt
            Case 1
                'Check if the current textbox is already reserved
                If TextBox1.Text = "RESERVED" Then
                    'Get a new number
                    Goto TryAgain
                End If
                TextBox1.Text = "RESERVED"
            Case 2
                TextBox2.Text = "RESERVED"
                'etc
        End Select
    ElseIf notification = 2 Then
        RandomInt = GetRandomInt(6, 10)
        Select RandomInt
            Case 5
                TextBox5.Text = "RESERVED"
            Case 6
                TextBox6.Text = "RESERVED"
                'etc
        End Select
    Else
        MsgBox("You entered an invalid number")
    End If

End Sub

Public Function GetRandomInt(ByVal StartNum As Integer, ByVal EndNum As Integer) As Integer
    Dim RandomClass As New Random()
    Dim RandomNumber As Integer
    RandomNumber = RandomClass.Next(StartNum, EndNum)

    GetRandomInt = RandomNumber

End Function
```

Good luck with the project.

Comment: What will be the a statement if the textboxes are all occupied from random?